# How does 麦 connect 烧麦 (shāomài), a kind of dumpling, with 大麦 (dàmài), 小麦 (xiǎomài), and 燕麦 (yànmài), which are types of grains?

Tags: food

This is 烧麦 (shāomài):

[image: Shaomai; Image source: Wikimedia commons https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pork_and_glutinous_rice_shaomai_by_jslander_at_Din_Tai_Fung,_Arcadia.jpg]

Which has the same character 麦 as in:

- 大麦 (dàmài = barley),
- 小麦 (xiǎomài = wheat), and
- 燕麦 (yànmài = oats).

These are types of grains, and seem unrelated to 烧麦.

**Question**: How does 麦 connect 烧麦 (shāomài), a kind of dumpling, with 大麦 (dàmài), 小麦 (xiǎomài), and 燕麦 (yànmài), types of grains?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's nothing to do with 麦 (grains).

From [wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%87%92%E8%B3%A3),

> 烧卖，又称稍麦、烧麦、捎卖、稍美、干蒸、烧梅、肖米、鬼蓬头。
>
> 烧卖及其他与之谐音的名称的来由有多种说法，没有定论。

It's explained a little in the [English version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shumai).

> The name was given "捎卖", meaning the product was "sold as a sideline", with tea.
>
> The name was later transformed into modern forms like "烧麦", "稍美" and "烧卖", changing the characters while keeping the original pronunciation.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  That would explain why it's the odd one out.